# Is it possible for a topology in a cluster to write into a txt-file on the local filesystem? (cluster running on the same system)

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Currently im working on a project, to geather sensor-values from a TI-SensorTag CC2650, send this values with an python script via HTTP (through an Apache-TomCat-Servlet) into Apache-Kafka and connect Kafka with Apache-Storm to process the data.

This data will be written to a .txt-file on my local system (the directory of the Apache-Storm-Cluster-Folder) by a bolt in the topology.

I've just started with Storm and Kafka a few week ago, and I was confused about the following:

If I run the topology on a local cluster, everything works fine. But if I submit it to a "normal" cluster, running on localhost:8888, then it simply does nothing.

The Storm-UI does show the topology, but it seems that there is no reaction on incoming messages from kafka.

Should'nt the test on a local cluster and the function on a real cluster be similar? Or does the cluster just not have the permission to write / modify files on my local system?

---

**Additional Information:**

---

**Overview** (connections between the "systems"):
[image: Overview of the connections of this project]

**How should it work?**

> When I write an message to an topic in Kafka, the Kafka-Spout of the topology should grab that message and write it down into an .txt-file on my local filesystem.

**My code (jar-with-dependencies) is located in:**

> "/home/tobias/storm/apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/mycode/StormKafkaTopology/target/"

and im trying to write in the **output.txt** located in:

> "/home/tobias/storm/apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/mycode/StromKafkaTopology"/tmp/"

**Code of the Topology:**

```
    public class StormKafkaTopology {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    String zkConnString = "localhost:2181";
    String topic = "mytopic";
    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnString);

    SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, "/" +topic, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    kafkaSpoutConfig.bufferSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    kafkaSpoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    //kafkaSpoutConfig.forceFromStart = true;
    kafkaSpoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("kafka-spout", new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig));
    builder.setBolt("printer-bolt", new PrinterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout");

    if (args != null && args.length >0) {
        config.setNumWorkers(6);
        config.setNumAckers(6);
        //config.setMaxSpoutPending(100);
        //config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(20);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("StormKafkaTopology", config, builder.createTopology());
    } else {
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("StormKafkaTopology", config, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(10000);
        cluster.killTopology("StormKafkaTopology");
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
}}
```

**Code for the PrinterBolt:**

```
public class PrinterBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {
/*
*   execute-method will be opened if tuples are processed
*/
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String msg = tuple.getString(0);
    System.out.println("======before write file======");
    try {
        // set file directory:
        File file = new File("/home/tobias/storm/apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating/mycode/StormKafkaTopology/tmp/output.txt");
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    //create a FileWriter
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    //create a BufferedWriter
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    //write into the file
    bw.write(msg + "\n");
    //close the BufferedWriter (IMPORTANT)
    bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("======after write file======");
    //you could emit some Date here for further processing:
    //collector.emit(new Values(msg));
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("output"));
}}
```

I would be greatful if someone would be able to point out my mistakes, and can give some advice.

Comment: did you check the worker logs ?

Comment: I've searched in 3 of my worker-xxxx.log logs, but did not find anything about this project in it.

Sorry for the question, but how do I identify which worker created which log? (I know the ports of the workers are similar to the numbers in the logfile-name, but how are they connected?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to run it "locally" then that is a good first step. Also it sounds like you're able to get to the Storm UI which is good. After you submit the topology, it should show up in the Storm UI and then you can click on it to see the spouts and bolts in the topology. Click each of the spouts/bolts and then click on the ports (one for each worker) to view the logs right in the UI.

My guess is that there is an error somewhere. Time to start digging through storm/kafka logs to find out what it is.

Q: How to identify which worker created which log? Each worker is assigned a port. Each worker log is a combination of topology name + port. For you, just find the most recent log and see what is in it.

A couple of things:

- Start with 1 worker, it is simpler
- [Update the logging in your PrinterBolt to use SLF4J](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2015/06/22/getting-started-with-storm-logging/) so that you can see messages in storm's logs and in the UI
- Add a try/catch and in the event of an exception use `collector.reportError(e);` to report the error. Then it'll show up red in the storm ui!
- Small clarification on your diagram, the Kafka broker port is 9092 not 2181... 2181 is for zookeeper only

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll have a look on your list of "things" and im sure that there are some really helpful quality of life improofments right there.

I just recognized that the topology does not show up any executors or workers (both 0) in the storm UI. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, it will show the executors and workers if I start the supervisor again ... but when I use the "bin/storm supervisor"-command then the supervisor is only showing up for a short period of time (<3 sec) in the storm-ui. Is this the normal case?

Comment: Sounds like your supervisor is crashing then. Did you run through storm setup and edit your storm.yaml? http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, to look into the storm.yaml. I had a typing mistake in the "storm.local.dir"-line, which caused the supervisor to crash after a few seconds.